# Photo slide Library

Tags: android, android-viewpager, preview

I want to achieve mac like image preview for android. Is there any library that can anchieve this. Something like this: [image: sliding images] but without the filenames below.

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes but take a look at these examples : https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157 it may give you a start

Answer (score 2):

Try with [3D Carousel View](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel).....